# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Unable to create new native thread

Tags: java, performance

I'm managing a Server-hosted Application whom users face an Error that says:

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Unable to create new native thread

I searched about it and found that it may be a problem of not having threads against the requested, but i found that the server has no problem with that as appears in memory state and CPU state attached as follows:

```
free -m    #Memory status
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:         10103       2946       7156          0         25         88
-/+ buffers/cache:       2832       7270
Swap:         1906         26       1880

# df -h    #Disk status
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda3       217G  172G   34G  84% /
udev            5.0G  4.0K  5.0G   1% /dev
tmpfs           2.0G  264K  2.0G   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            5.0G     0  5.0G   0% /run/shm
/dev/sda1       189M   33M  146M  19% /boot
```

And this is the Processor state info:

```
# ps aux | wc -l  #Number of Running Processes
92
# ulimit -a | grep "max user"   #Maximum allowed Users Processes
max user processes              (-u) 80711
# ps axms | wc -l  #Number of Running Threads
376
# cat /proc/sys/kernel/threads-max #Maximum allowed Number of Threads
161422
```

This is the TOP output showing that Java service is taking  3G as Virtual memory and 2.5G as Resident size:

[image: top command screenshot]

Comment: Probably an application error. `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` is the actual problem, ` Unable to create new native thread` is what java was trying to do when it got the error.

Comment: If this is a 32 bit java, then 3 gb is about the max it can use.